Examples of lexical scoping in js other than nested functions?
I was trying to understand the lexical scoping. I gone through here and I found all examples are related to nested functions. Is lexical scope only related to nested functions and parent to child accessibility?
Are there any examples of lexical scoping in js other than nested functions and closures?
AND
Does function parameters also form lexical scoping? For example:
function greet(name) {
    console.log("Hello, " + name + "!");
}

greet("Alice"); // Output: "Hello, Alice!"
greet("Bob"); // Output: "Hello, Bob!"


"all examples are related to nested functions" - that's because all the answers contrast lexical scoping with dynamic scoping, where the difference is about function scopes in particular. Scoping in general of course works with other kinds of scopes as well - but both lexical scoping and dynamic scoping have the same behaviour with respect to block scopes.

All scopes in javascript are lexical. Yes, that includes the global scope, module scopes, block scopes, and function scopes (for variables declared by parameters, top-level let/const/class declarations, and var declarations).

Lexical scoping applies to any blocks, not just blocks with nested functions.


function testfun() {
  let a = 1;
  {
    let a = 2;
    a++;
    console.log(a); // 3
  }
  console.log(a); // 1
}

testfun();



Note that only variables declared with let or const are block-scoped. Variables declared with var have function scope, so if you used var a in the above example they would be the same variable in the same scope. Before ES6, we would have used an IIFE to implement similar scoping.
Function parameters are scoped as if they're declared in the top-level block of the function.

You are using let a =1 and console.log(a) which prints 1 in the same block. How this example shows the lexical scoping?

It shows that it's not changed by the a variable in the nested block. If you changed all the let to var you would get 3 as the last output.
